# Can I convert a sequence of PropertyInfo to an Expression?

Tags: c#, lambda, reflection, linq-expressions

I'm writing some validation code that uses reflection to walk an object graph to find types that implement some conventional static methods with a certain attribute.

I end up with the root `object`, sequence of `PropertyInfo` to access the class that implements the static method and the `MethodInfo` for the static method itself.

I want to write a method to invoke the static method, using the root `object` as a parameter. My current implementation looks something like this.

```
private static ValidateOptionsResult InvokeValidation<TConfig>(
        TConfig root,
        IImmutableStack<PropertyInfo> path,
        MethodInfo target)
{
    object node = root;
    foreach (var accessorInfo in path)
    {
        node = accessorInfo.GetMethod.Invoke(
                node,
                new object[]
                    {
                    });
    }

    return (ValidateOptionsResult)target.Invoke(
            null,
            new object[]
                {
                    node
                });
}
```

I haven't tested this yet but I think it explains what I mean.

The question is, is there a better way to do this by building an [`Expression`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.expressions.expression?view=netcore-2.2) rather than chaining invokes? By better, I mean faster performing when it is actually called.

This method will be used to register an [`IValidateOptions<TOptions>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-2.2#options-validation) and this validation will be invoked whenever `TOptions` is injected. Its important that this code should perform optimally.

Answer (score 2):

John Skeet has a great write up on this topic.

Making Reflection Fly and Exploring Delegates, Jon Skeet. 
https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2008/08/09/making-reflection-fly-and-exploring-delegates/

Essentially, you will cache delegate functions and then call the cached delegate. On the first call creating the delegate will be slow since you are still using reflection, but on subsequent calls it will be MUCH faster using the cached delegate. His post indicates that cached delegate are about 600 times faster that using Invoke.